# How to disable semicolon rule on type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

tslint is replacing the comma with a semi-colon:

```js
async foo(): Promise<Array<{ a: A, b: string }>> {
async foo(): Promise<Array<{ a: A; b: string }>> {
//                               ^
```

How can I can disable it?

Comment: /* tslint:disable-next-line:RULENAME */